# How to Show Date Below Format In Android And Php Script

Tags: php, android, string, date, date-format

Any One Tell Me how to Show Date Below Format In My Android `Textview` And my Php Script.

**2016-03-15 14:46:00_India Standard Time_Asia/Kolkata_GMT+05:30**

Comment: Please show some effort that you at least tried something.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to accomplish this.

```
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss_zzzz_ZZZZ");
String myDateString = myFormat.format(myDatetime)
```